# Upgrade OSX GM to final version

Tags: upgrade, mac-appstore, macos

I want to install OSX Yosemite GM, but final version will release soon, can I upgrade Yosemite GM to final through Appstore when apple release final version?
or I have to download another 5GB ?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150949/upgrade-to-final-release-of-yosemite-from-gold-master

Comment: The last GM and final version is the same build : 14A388a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You don't need to.

Apple is regarding the last GM and last public beta *as* the final release of Yosemite and not offering an update path. Instead, wait for 10.10.1 and the Mac App Store will include this as an update path putting you back on track.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download 5GB ;)

However a clean install can be a great idea after a Dev Preview...

Answer (score 0):

As you have the GM, I assume you have access to the Developer Panel. If so, download the final release they publish there, as the App Store thinks you've already got it installed. You need to run the newly downloaded install, maybe from the OS, maybe from boot.